# Не могу подключить два разных компа. Socket python

Tags: python

Решил написать консольный чат 
И все было хорошо, но как только я начал использовать не localhost Клиент не может присоединиться к моему серверу

server

```py
import socket
from threading import Thread

LOCALHOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 9090
server = socket.socket()
server.bind((LOCALHOST, PORT))
server.listen(1)

print('Server started...')
clientConnection, clientAddress = server.accept()
print('Connected client:', clientAddress)
msg = ''


def listen():
    while True:
        try:
            in_data = clientConnection.recv(1024)
            message = in_data.decode()
            if message == 'bye':
                break
            print(f'From client: {message}')
        except socket.error:
            print("Lost connection to client [L]")
            clientConnection.close()
            break


def send():
    while True:
        try:
            out_data = input()
            clientConnection.send(bytes(out_data, 'UTF-8'))
        except socket.error:
            print("Lost connection to client [S]")
            clientConnection.close()
            break


thread_listen = Thread(target=listen)
thread_send = Thread(target=send)

thread_listen.start()
thread_send.start()

thread_listen.join()
thread_send.join()
```

client

```py
import socket
from threading import Thread

SERVER = 'localhost'
PORT = 9090

client = socket.socket()
client.connect((SERVER, PORT))
client.sendall(bytes('This from Client', 'UTF-8'))
print("Connected to server")


def listen():
    while True:
        try:
            in_data = client.recv(1024)
            print('From server:', in_data.decode())
        except socket.error:
            print('Lost connection to server [L]')
            client.close()
            break


def send():
    while True:
        try:
            out_data = input()
            client.sendall(bytes(out_data, 'UTF-8'))
            if out_data == 'bye':
                break
        except socket.error:
            print('Lost connection to server [S]')
            client.close()
            break


thread_listen = Thread(target=listen)
thread_send = Thread(target=send)

thread_listen.start()
thread_send.start()

thread_listen.join()
thread_send.join()
```

если использовать localhost все работает
когда использую свой IP то вот что выдает

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/IIG/PycharmProjects/client/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    client.connect((SERVER, PORT))
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера
```

ipconfig

```
Настройка протокола IP для Windows


Адаптер Ethernet Ethernet:

   Состояние среды. . . . . . . . : Среда передачи недоступна.
   DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . : Dlink

Адаптер беспроводной локальной сети Подключение по локальной сети* 11:

   Состояние среды. . . . . . . . : Среда передачи недоступна.
   DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . :

Адаптер Ethernet Ethernet 2:

   Состояние среды. . . . . . . . : Среда передачи недоступна.
   DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . :

Адаптер беспроводной локальной сети Беспроводная сеть:

   DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . : Dlink
   Локальный IPv6-адрес канала . . . : fe80::fc74:1b77:b928:5f71%6
   IPv4-адрес. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.215
   Маска подсети . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Основной шлюз. . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Туннельный адаптер isatap.Dlink:

   Состояние среды. . . . . . . . : Среда передачи недоступна.
   DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . : Dlink
```

Answer (score 2):

Привязка к [localhost](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)

```
server.bind((LOCALHOST, PORT))
```

означает, что сервер будет слушать соединения приходящие только на localhost, то есть с того же хоста, где сервер запущен.

Как и подключение клиента к localhost

```
SERVER = 'localhost'
...
client.connect((SERVER, PORT))
```

означает, что клиент попытается подключиться к тому же компьютеру, на котором запущен.

Используйте маршрутизируемые IP-адреса и убедитесь, что трафик между хостами ни что не ограничивает.

Comment: а какой IP мне нужно использовать на SERVER

Comment: @regdayzk адрес сервера или пустую строку для прослушивания всех адресов.

Comment: у сервера поставил '', а у клиента IP своего пк(на котором и запущен сервер) с https://2ip.ru
И это не работает

Comment: Они в одной подсети находятся?

Comment: Когда они в одной подсети оно работает
Но когда не в одной не работает

Comment: Значит либо между сетями нет маршрутизации, либо порт блокируется одним из хопов.

Comment: Как мне это проверить
И что такое "хопов"

Comment: Первым делом стоит проверить ping с клиентского хоста на адрес сервера.  Предполагается, что сетевой программист прежде, чем взяться за собственно программирование, должен знать модель OSI, основные протоколы, включая IP и TCP, различать частные адреса, уметь считать маски, понимать принципы коммутации и маршрутизации, знать, что такое NAT, уметь пользоваться средствами диагностики сети, типа traceroute, и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Ping'ом я проверил сразу как оно не подключилось
И там все работает

Comment: Операционная система сервера какая?

Comment: Стоит windows 10,а у клиента windows 7

Comment: Что на сервере показывает команда `ipconfig`?

Comment: Я добавил результат в низ вопроса

Comment: У шлюза на WAN-интерфейсе белый IP-адрес? Проброс порта 9090 на шлюзе настроен?

Comment: белый 
А вот что касается проброса то не настроем
Я правильно понимаю что это делается на маршрутизаторе?

Comment: Да, в настройках устройства надо указать, что подключения к порту 9090 маршрутизатора должны перенаправляться на порт 9090 сервера из локальной сети.

Comment: Можете посмотреть?
Это должно выглядеть так
[https://yadi.sk/i/iBIourBMmp7t6A]

Comment: Да, должно работать.

Comment: Все по старому
Не коннектится

Comment: Значит ещё какая-то сетевая проблема осталась. Но вряд ли её удастся диагностировать по переписке.