# Python3, [WinError 10060] в socket-приложении

Tags: python, сокет

Есть сервер:

```
hosted = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 11719

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((hosted,port))
s.listen(3)
```

Есть клиент:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("айпи сервера", 11719))
```

При подключении клиента к серверу с устройства, находящегося в другой сети, возникает ошибка:

```
"s.connect(("айпи сервера", 11719))  [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной ..."
```

Как фиксить, не прибегая к использованию UDP(SOCK_DGRAM)? Учитывая то, что я как минимум командир чайников, хотелось бы получить развернутый ответ.

Comment: На ваш вопрос невозможно дать ответ, тем более развёрнутый. Нужна диагностика сети между хостами - есть ли маршрутизация между хостами, не скрыт ли один из хостов или оба за NAT, не заблокированы ли порты и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу подключить два разных компа. Socket python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/960617/204271)

Comment: В фаерволе исключения добавьте. Виндовс блокирует подключения из других сетей