# Написал клиент и сервер на Python, не работает на разных компьютерах. На одном компьютере работает. Что делать?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, сервер, сокет

Есть два компьютера находящихся в одной wifi сети. Когда запускаю на одном из них и клиент и сервер, то они (программы) прекрасно общаются. Когда запускаю сервер на одном компьютере а клиент на другом, то они не соединяются. Не знаю в чем проблема. Использую один из открытых портов (ввел `netstat -a` и выбрал 127.0.0.1:4262 для TCP). 
Вот код клиента и сервера (но они работают вроде):
**Сервер:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket
import time

# socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = int(input("Enter port: "))

clients = []

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host,port))

quit = False
print("[ SERVER STARTED AT: {} ]".format(s.getsockname()))

while not quit:
    try:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)

        if addr not in clients:
            clients.append(addr)

        itsatime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S", time.localtime())

        print('[{}:{}][{}]{}'.format(
            addr[0], addr[1], itsatime, data.decode("utf-8")
        ))

        for client in clients:
            if addr != client:
                s.sendto(data,client)
    except: 
        print("\n[ SERVER STOPPED ]")
        quit = True

s.close()
```

**Клиент:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket
import threading
import time
import random
import json

shutdown = False
join = False

def receving (name, sock):
    while not shutdown:
        try:
            while True:
                data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
                print(data.decode("utf-8"))
                time.sleep(0.2)
        except:
            pass

host = '127.0.0.1' # socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 0
#print(host, port)

NICK = 'user'
PASSWORD = 'user'
ID = random.randint(0, 5000)

try:
    with open('settings.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as settings:
        conf = json.load(settings)
        NICK = conf['nickname']
        PASSWORD = conf['password']
        ID = conf['id']
        print('You logged as {}'.format(NICK))
except:
    NICK = input('New nickname: ')
    PASSWORD = input('Password: ')
    with open('settings.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as settings:
        settings.write(json.dumps(
            { 'nickname' : NICK,
              'password': PASSWORD,
              'id': ID
            }, ensure_ascii=False
        ))

server_ip = input('INPUT SERVER IP: ')
server_port = input('INPUT SERVER PORT: ')
server = (server_ip, int(server_port))

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.setblocking(0)

rT = threading.Thread(target = receving, args = ("RecvThread", s))
rT.start()

while shutdown == False:
    if join == False:
        try:
            s.sendto(("[{}] => join chat".format(NICK)).encode("utf-8"), server)
            join = True
        except OSError: 
            shutdown = True
            print('Error: server down!')
            break
    else:
        try:
            message = input()
            # crypt
            if message != "":
                s.sendto(("[{}] :: {}".format(NICK, message)).encode("utf-8"), server)
            time.sleep(0.2)
        except:
            s.sendto(("[{}] <= left chat ".format(NICK)).encode("utf-8"), server)
            shutdown = True

rT.join()
s.close()
```

**ПОМОГИТЕ ПЖ!**

Еще попытался написать то же самое на C++, но тут уже другая проблема. Когда запускаю сервер и начинаю прослушивать, то сыпется всякая дичь, как будто порт занят (проверил на многих, везде так)... Вот код на **c++**:

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include "string"
#include "iostream"
#include "winsock2.h" //ws2_32.lib
using namespace std;

//Machine - базовый класс для SERVER и CLIENT
class Machine
{
protected:
    string IP; //ip
    short int PORT; //port
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVersion;
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int size_of_addr;
    SOCKET s_connect;
public:
    Machine()
    {
        cout << "Enter ip address: "; //127.0.0.1
        cin >> IP;
        cout << "Enter port: "; //9090
        cin >> PORT;
        start();
    }
    Machine(string IP, short int PORT)
    {
        this->IP = IP;
        this->PORT = PORT;
        start();
    }
    void start()
    {
        DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
        if (WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData) != 0)
        {
            error("Error: cant load socket!");
        }
        size_of_addr = sizeof(addr);
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP.c_str());
        addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    }
    void error(string msg)
    {
        cout << msg << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
};

//SERVER
class Server : Machine
{
private:
    SOCKET s_listen;
public:
    Server() : Machine()
    {
        start_server();
    }
    Server(string IP, short int PORT) : Machine(IP, PORT)
    {
        start_server();
    }
    void start_server()
    {
        s_listen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
        bind(s_listen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, size_of_addr);
        listen(s_listen, SOMAXCONN);

        s_connect = accept(s_listen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &size_of_addr);
        if (s_connect == 0)
        {
            error("Error: cant connect!");
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Client connected." << endl;
        }
        cout << "Server started" << endl;
        while (true)
        {
            char buff[256];
            recv(s_connect, buff, 256, NULL);
            cout << buff << endl;
            // send(s_connect, buff, 256, NULL);
        }
    }
};

//CLIENT
class Client : Machine
{
public:
    Client() : Machine()
    {
        start_client();
    }
    Client(string IP, short int PORT) : Machine(IP, PORT)
    {
        start_client();
    }
    void start_client()
    {
        s_connect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
        if (connect(s_connect, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, size_of_addr) != 0)
        {
            error("Error! Failed to connect to server!");
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Connected to the server!" << endl;
        }
        while (true)
        {
            string message;
            string nick = "Re";
            cout << nick << ":";
            getline(cin, message);
            send(s_connect, message.c_str(), 256, NULL);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    Server* server = new Server();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `127.0.0.1` - это алиас для этого компьютера. а еще инициализируйте поля в конструкторе.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу подключить два разных компа. Socket python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/960617/204271)

Comment: Вы использовали 127.0.0.1 на *разных* компьютерах? но это же на каждом компьютере его адрес... Используйте реальные адреса машин.

Comment: Спасибо всем! Попробую

Comment: Python заработал, C++ неа(

Answer (score 1):

На  сервере нужно не 127.0.0.1, а 0.0.0.0, работать думаю будет